# DLL para criptografar uma string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll

Como criar uma DLL em C# com Interop para trafegar dados entre aplicações usando criptografia/decriptografia de uma string que será enviada e recebida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina métodos públicos em sua `DLL`, adicione a referência dela em seu projeto, e depois vai trocando informações entre o seu projeto e a `DLL`. Para gerar, todo projeto que você compila, vira uma `DLL` na pasta bin. O ideal é você criar um projeto somente para isso, e depois adicionar a referência. Acho que isso basta. Faço assim.

Comment: Eu criei a DLL já, e está funcionando certo. 
Minha dúvida é: Fui informado para fazer uma com "com Interop", o que seria isto? Não estou encontrando materiais suficientes, para compreender corretamente.

Comment: Mas como essa parte da DLL já está concluída, irei abrir outra pergunta.